# Querying firestore with orderBy whereEqual and startAfter

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to make a`recyclerView` with pagination in my project. However, I got stuck on the process.

My firestore data is built as follows (some of the documents has visibility=false as a value so I dont want them to appear):

[image]

Now, I had like to get the first 5 documents ordered by `dateCreated` and then to continue pagination by the last value that I previously received.

I tried using the following:

```
db
    .collection( "Quotes" )
    .whereEqualTo( "visibility", true )
    .orderBy("dateCreated", Query.Direction.DESCENDING )
    .startAfter("dateCreated", dateCreatedOrig
    .get(dateCreatedOrig.size()-1))
    .limit(5)
    .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        ...
                    }

                }

                dAdapter = new Ddapter(...);
                ddapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                rv_Quotes.setAdapter( ddapter );

            }
        } );
```

Where `dateCreatedOrig` is List that contains the timestamp of the first query so I get the last time stamp to continue the pagination from there.

However, I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many arguments provided to startAfter(). The number of arguments must be less than or equal to the number of orderBy() clauses.

Any ideas?

Comment: `get()` doesn't take any parameters.  Also, you didn't close the parenthesis on the call to `startAfter()`.  This is evident after I reformatted your code in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by get() doesnt take any parameters? It should take or shouldnt? From my experience so far I never inserted parameters into it, like in this case.

Comment: Look at the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get()) for clarity.  Unless you have a Source object to pass, it doesn't take arguments.  Your code is apparently trying to pass `dateCreatedOrig.size()-1)`?

Comment: dateCreateOrig is a lost that contains dates from the first query. For example, the first time I loaded 5 results I got a list of 5 values of Timestamp like 19.12.2020, 21.12.2020, 24.12.2020, 26.12.2020...Then, when I tried to paginage I wanted it to startAfter a document that its dateCreated is after the 21.12.2020 for example, which will load the next 5 documents. When I wrote dateCreatedOrog.size()-1 I tried to get the timestamp of the last document from my first query. I mean, If I pass startAfter with empty value, how can it know from where to start the bext query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are passing 2 arguments to `startAfter`. If you see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#startAfter(java.lang.Object...)) for `startAfter`, you will see that it:

> Creates and returns a new Query that starts after the provided fields relative to the order of the query. The order of the field values must match the order of the order by clauses of the query

Meaning that you define the field name that will be used in the `orderBy` clause, not the `startAfter`, and both should be used together. So in you case, all that needs to be done it removing the first argument of `startAt` and it will work, so it could look like this:

```
db.collection( "Quotes" )
  .whereEqualTo( "visibility", true )
  .orderBy("dateCreated", Query.Direction.DESCENDING )
  .startAfter(dateCreatedOrig.get(dateCreatedOrig.size()-1))
  .limit(5)
  .get()
  .addOnCompleteListener(...);
```

Comment: Glad to help :)